# How can I concatenate / join two bash variables by a newline character?

Tags: bash, join, newline, concatenation

My non-working code sample (erroneous line -> empty=$empty\n$url):

```
empty=""
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $s; do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
      url="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      echo $url
      empty=$empty\n$url
    else
      echo "$s does not match"
    fi
done

echo $empty|sort -f -t/ -k 4
```

I try to rebuild the modified lines splitted by the for cycle.

Answer (score 2):

```
empty="$empty"$'\n'"$url"
```

`$'\n'` is a literal newline in bash (double-quoting the variable references is not strictly necessary here, but helps readability; alternative: `empty=${empty}$'\n'${url}`).

Alternative solution with `printf`:

```
printf -v empty '%s\n%s' "$empty" "$url"
```

Comment: Also `empty+=$'\n'"$url"`

Answer (score 0):

String literals can have embedded newlines:

```
entry="$entry
$url"
```

or

```
entry+="
$url"
```